# Can't we have some achdus?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla

Why don't the main Halachic authorities (e.g. R' Ovadyah Yoseph, the Hasidic Rebbes, etc.) come together to make one Nussach for everyone; combining the Minhagim (e.g. Temani pronounciation, Yekkish fast days, lots of Piyutim, Hasidic Yom Tovim, some Sephardic leniencies, etc.)? It would create a lot of achdus - the kind of thing that got us the Torah.

Comment: for right or wrong, people take the quote 4 lines up from the bottom really seriously http://images.e-daf.com/DafImg.asp?ID=1215&size=1

Comment: In a perfect world...Hacham Yishak says by the time of Mashiah everyone will be Sefaradi:)

Comment: But all my minhagim are the best!

Comment: Why not take the Sefardic stringencies? There are a bunch.

Comment: @Hacham How confidence-inspiring :/

Comment: @DoubleAA Ashkenazim have it lot easier foodwise. Bet Yosef, Yashan, Pat Yisrael, Bishul Yisrael- every Humra by food taken by the Sefaradim. Oh sorry we can eat rice and corn for a week while you can't big deal!

Comment: @Hacham I know. That's why I called the OP out on it. Incidentally, you are more meikil about nat-bar-nat issues.

Comment: @DoubleAA ya but even some Sefaradim are Mahmir in some Nat Bar Nat cases like the Ashkenazim.

Comment: Wait a sec... I thought that when משיח comes, we will all follow בית שמאי!

Comment: @Hacham Gabriel The chasidim say moshiach will have to be sefardi. So far all the false ones have been. Otherwise they would never agree with him.

Comment: Please present a source for you idea that achdus= following the same minhagim/piskei dinim.

Comment: Wasn't that sort of the intention behind Nusach Ari? I seem to remember reading something along those lines in the introduction to Siddur Tehilas Hashem.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Also, you guys can trust a Kefeila which means your food is almost never treif because stainless steel pots don't give any flavor.

Comment: Some proper formulation based on Minhag Ashkenaz and Minhag Teiman seems the only answer, of course then would have to discount much of the Jewish population.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achdus does not mean we all have the same menu, Achdus means we care and lookout for each other.

Imagine a family where each member takes different medications and someone comes along and says 'why don't you have Achdus?' 'Get all your doctors together and come up with medications that is equal for all!'

The Achdus that got us the Torah in the first place was that all the Jews were one heart with each other without animosity towards each other and not that they all had the same taste in mind when eating the Mahn!

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote this. While you have presented an important aspect of achdus, you present it as the ideal. When Sanhedrin returns we will be done with the different divisions, and that's the way it is supposed to be. The current situation is bedieved. So yes, the ideal goal is to have the same menu and that does contribute significantly to achdus.

Comment: With different 'menus' everyone hates each other. The Hasidim hate the Sephardim, the Ashkenazim hate the Hasidim, etc.